# Possible to use the .Find command to find the next cell with a specific background/fill color?

Tags: excel, vba

Right now I have a code that creates a range starting at a specific, user-defined cell. I am currently defining the end of the range by the next cell that has any text in it, as such:

```
topRowDelete = pnRange.Find(deletePartNumber, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
```

This defines the top row to be deleted by finding the cell that matches `deletePartNumber`, which is a defined by user input. The bottom row to delete is then defined by:

```
btmRowDelete = pnRange.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row - 1
```

This finds the next row with a non-blank cell, then offsets it by one.  Now I know the top and bottom rows of the range to delete, so I can simply redefine the range and delete as follows:

```
Set pnRange = Rows(topRowDelete & ":" & btmRowDelete)
pnRange.Delete
```

Works like a charm.

The **problem** is that the `btmRowDelete` definition only works if the user has input text in one of the cells below. In practice, they should have done this. But it is not always the case. So then the `btmRowDelete` might be defined incorrectly if the user has not filled in all of the cells as they should.

**However**, I do know for certain that the next cell that should define `btmRowDelete` will **always** be a specific fill color, which is different from the cells in between.
*Is there a way to modify the .Find command to find the next cell in the range with a specific fill color, instead of the next one that contains text*?

Comment: `.Find` supports finding a cell of a specific color. I would recommend recording a macro and then work on the code

Comment: @SiddharthRout How can I manually execute a "Find" command so that the code I want is mimicked by the record macro function? I'm looking here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find at the available arguments for .Find and I don't see any of them that would appear to work for cell fill color.

Comment: **1.** Start Recording a macro **2.** Press CTRL+F to launch the find window **3.** In the dialog box, click on format dropdown, select the color. **4.** Click on `Find` **5.** Stop recording and check VBA code. The code will be in a module.

Comment: You will need to set the `Application.FindFormat` search criteria prior to performing the search. [Select all colored cells from conditional formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46151307/select-all-colored-cells-from-conditional-formatting/46152251#46152251) may be of use...

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of your data? Could you share an example address of the initial `pnRange`? Is it a single-column range? What happens with `btmRowDelete` when the cell stays empty? Is there an error or is the result wrong? Do you know the specific color of the cell? Do you know the column where the cell should be found? I'm asking because the Find method cannot find a cell color different than another color and it can find only a blank, an empty, or a populated cell with a specified color.

Comment: @Tragamor Thanks, this is what I what missing. I was able to set the `Application.FindFormat` to the correct RGB color, then use the `SearchFormat:=True` argument in the `pnRage.Find` function to get what I needed. You guys are awesome!

Comment: @VBasic2008 Luckily I was able to figure it out with the aforementioned technique. I would post a picture if I knew how to host an image >_>

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DeletePartNumber( _
    ByVal PartNumberRange As Range, _
    ByVal PartNumber As String)
Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Part Number"

Dim tCell As Range, rCount As Long

With PartNumberRange
    
    ' Reference the top cell.
    
    Set tCell = .Find(What:=PartNumber, _
        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    If tCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Part number '" & PartNumber & "' not found.", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Calculate the number of rows of the search range.
    rCount = .Rows.Count + .Row - 1 - tCell.Row
    
End With

' Check if it is the last cell of the range (should never happen).
If rCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "The part number is in the last row of the range.", _
       vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Exit Sub
End If

' Retrieve the color of the top cell.
Dim tColor As Long: tColor = tCell.Interior.Color
' For the color of the cell below instead you can use:
'Dim tColor As Long: tColor = tCell.Offset(1).Interior.Color

' Reference the next cell with a different color, the bottom cell.

Dim bCell As Range

For Each bCell In tCell.Offset(1).Resize(rCount).Cells
    If bCell.Interior.Color <> tColor Then Exit For
Next bCell

If bCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Part number '" & PartNumber _
        & "' last row not found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
    Exit Sub
End If
         
' Delete the entire rows from the top to the bottom cells.
With tCell
    .Resize(bCell.Row - .Row + 1).EntireRow.Delete
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Next Cell With a Different Color

- I don't know exactly what your data looks like, but IMO, using the Find method, to get the bottom cell, might not apply i.e. it might work until it doesn't, for the reasons explained in the comments.
- The following applies only to a single-column range.

**Utilization**

```vb
Sub DeletePartNumberTEST()
    ' The 'Debug.Print' lines show how the range changes when rows are deleted.
    
    Dim PartNumber As String: PartNumber = 1
    
    Dim pnRange As Range: Set pnRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A20")
    Debug.Print "Before Deletion: " & pnRange.Address
    
    DeletePartNumber pnRange, PartNumber
    Debug.Print "After Deletion: " & pnRange.Address

End Sub
```

**The Method**

```vb
Sub DeletePartNumber( _
        ByVal PartNumberRange As Range, _
        ByVal PartNumber As String)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Part Number"
    
    Dim tCell As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With PartNumberRange
        
        ' Reference the top cell.
        
        Set tCell = .Find(What:=PartNumber, _
            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
        If tCell Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Part number '" & PartNumber & "' not found.", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Calculate the number of rows of the search range.
        rCount = .Rows.Count + .Row - 1 - tCell.Row
        
    End With

    ' Check if it is the last cell of the range (should never happen).
    If rCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The part number is in the last row of the range.", _
           vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Retrieve the color of the top cell.
    Dim tColor As Long: tColor = tCell.Interior.Color
    ' For the color of the cell below instead you can use:
    'Dim tColor As Long: tColor = tCell.Offset(1).Interior.Color
    
    ' Reference the next cell with a different color, the bottom cell.
    
    Dim bCell As Range
    
    For Each bCell In tCell.Offset(1).Resize(rCount).Cells
        If bCell.Interior.Color <> tColor Then Exit For
    Next bCell
    
    If bCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Part number '" & PartNumber _
            & "' last row not found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
             
    ' Delete the entire rows from the top to the bottom cells.
    With tCell
        .Resize(bCell.Row - .Row + 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    
End Sub
```